# ScrollView is not automatically moving up when keyboard is visible

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, scrollview, textfield

I am facing a problem in moving my srollview up when keyboard appears on screen.
    I am having 4 textfields on my screen and all are number keypad textfields which dont have a next/done return key so for that i have added custom toolbar with previous and next button on it in my keyboard.
    So when i move from one textfield to another textfield using next button , cursor moves properly to the next field but scrollview dont move up so my textfield hides behind the keyboard. I have added scrollview to my storyboard and set delegates of textfield as well.

**Code:**

```
override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
        keyboardVisible = false
    }


   override open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()

    }



func registerForKeyboardNotifications ()-> Void   {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

    }

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications () -> Void {
        let center:  NotificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        center.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
        center.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)


    }





func keyboardWasShown (_ notification: Notification) {
        if(keyboardVisible == true){
            return
        }

        print(scrollView)
        if let keyboardSize = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            offset = scrollView!.contentOffset
            print(offset)

            var viewFrame = scrollView!.frame
            viewFrame.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
            scrollView!.frame = viewFrame

            var textFieldRect = activeField?.frame
            textFieldRect?.origin.y += 10;
            scrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(textFieldRect!, animated: true)

            keyboardVisible = true;


        }


    }

  func keyboardWillBeHidden (_ notification: Notification) {

        if(keyboardVisible == false){
            return;
        }
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight)
        scrollView?.contentOffset  = offset

        keyboardVisible = false


    }


// textfield delegate

//in textfieldDidBeginEditing i m setting custom toolbar on textfield input accesory view
open func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if(textField == myTextField1){
            myTextField1.inputAccessoryView = myCustomToolbar
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.previousButton.isEnabled = false
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.title = "Next"
        }else if(textField == myTextField2){
            myTextField2.inputAccessoryView = myCustomToolbar
            myCustomToolbar?.previousButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.title = "Next"
        }else if(textField == myTextField3){
            myTextField3.inputAccessoryView = myCustomToolbar
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.previousButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.title = "Next"
        }else if(textField == myTextField4){
            myTextField4.inputAccessoryView = myCustomToolbar
            myCustomToolbar?.nextButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.previousButton.isEnabled = true
            myCustomToolbar?.changeNextToActionButton(withTitle: "Some title")
        }
    }


   open func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        activeField = textField
        return true
    }


//PnPToolbar Delegate

    public func pnPToolbarNextButtonClicked(_ myCustomToolbar: myCustomToolbar!) {
        if(myTextField1.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else if(myTextField2.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else if(myTextField3.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField4.becomeFirstResponder()

        }else if(ifscCode.isFirstResponder){
            //Done call your method
            self.myMethod()
        }
        var textFieldRect = activeField?.frame
        textFieldRect?.origin.y += 10;
        scrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(textFieldRect!, animated: true)
    }

    public func myCustomToolbarPreviousButtonClicked(_ myCustomToolbar: myCustomToolbar!) {
        if(myTextField4.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else if(myTextField3.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        }else if(myTextField2.isFirstResponder){
            myTextField1.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        var textFieldRect = activeField?.frame
        textFieldRect?.origin.y += 10;
        scrollView!.scrollRectToVisible(textFieldRect!, animated: true)

    }
```

when i move from myTextField1 to myTextField2 cursor comes to second textfield but scrollview does not move up and content size of the scrollview also not moves up beyond the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage your flag in TextField's delegate as below :

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        keyboardVisible = true
    }

    func textFieldEndEditings(sender:UITextField) -> Void {
        print(sender.text)
        keyboardVisible = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For toolbar above the keyboard

```
let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
numberToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelNumberPad"),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneWithNumberPad")]
    numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
    phonenumberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar
```